# How to retrieve data from a website

Tags: php, authentication, extract

I would like to retrieve some data from a couple of different websites(that is - all my different stream revenues) and display them on a single page, on my website.
Note that in order to read the current revenue I have to log in all those websites, than navigate through some pages and finally retrieve data.
Any idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need and use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.curl.php)/[file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php) and then [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace.php) to get what you want.
Now, the coding part is your job.

Comment: It's ok. But from future if you want to notify someone then write @Ankit because only Ankit don't notify